# How can use ClassPathResource without @PoweMockito -UNit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

```java
ClassPathResource classPathResource = mock(ClassPathResource.class);
whenNew(ClassPathResource.class).withArguments("studentInfo.json").thenReturn(classPathResource);
```

How should I write a Spring test without `PowerMockito`?

`whenNew` and `withArguments` structures are used in `PowerMockito`, how can I do them only with `@SpringBootTest` and without `PowerMockito`

After that I will read the mockito file and check the existence of the file.

Comment: Why should you check a file in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this;

```
@SpringBootTest
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @BeforeClass
    void init() {
        File file = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data/file.txt").getFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, they later said there was no need for this check. @muhammed-ozbilici